# How do i store images in distributed system the right way?

Tags: web, file-upload, filesystems, mobile-application, distributed-system

I'm trying to create a distributed system which contains mobile app, web userpanel and an API that communicates with DB. I want the user to be able to upload a profile image both from the mobile app and the web userpanel but what is the best and "right" way to store images accross a distributed system? Cant really find anything describing best practices on this topic.

I know that the filepath should be in database, and the image in a file system. But should that file system be on the API server or where?

Here is an diagram of what i think the distributed system should be like.
[image: My idea of distributed system with image storage]

Answer (score 1):

The "right" way to do something complex like image hosting depends on factors like expected traffic and performance expectations. Designing large systems involves a lot of tradeoffs, so it's best to nail down what the requirements are for your system are in order to make decisions that serve those requirements.

As for your question, this diagram is roughly correct - you want to store the location of the uploaded image separate from the image itself. If you wanted your solution to be more scalable, an approach would be turning your file system into its own service with its own API. You would store a hash of the file in your database to reference it rather than its path, then request that image (or a URL to that image) from the new storage service by asking the storage service's API for the file that has the stored hash.

The reason this is more scalable is that the storage service is free to become its own distributed system when we don't require that every file has an associated file system path within a single namespace. A hash is a good candidate for a replacement of the filesystem path, but you could come up with your own storage ID scheme depending on your needs.

However, this may be wildly out of scope for what you are trying to design. If you only expect to have a few thousand users, storing your images and database on your API server in the file system isn't necessarily wrong, but you might experience growing pains if the requirements of your system grow.

Google's site reliability engineer classroom has a lesson on building a distributed image server, which is an adjacent problem to what you're looking to do: https://sre.google/classroom/imageserver/